# Partition specific sets

Tags: clojure

I want to use clojure to partition specific sets:

For example:
There is a vector `[1 2 3 4 5]`. Also there is a map here, like `{2 1, 3 1}`, which means generate 1 set that contains 2 elements, and 1 set that contains 3 elements.

```
(some_function {2 1, 3 1} [1 2 3 4 5])
;; I only want to these: 
 (([1 2 3] [4 5]) 
 ([1 2 4] [3 5]) 
 ([1 2 5] [3 4]) 
 ([1 2] [3 4 5]) 
 ([1 3 4] [2 5]) 
 ([1 3 5] [2 4]) 
 ([1 3] [2 4 5]) 
 ([1 4 5] [2 3]) 
 ([1 4] [2 3 5]) 
 ([1 5] [2 3 4]))
```

Previously, I thought to use [`(combo/partitions [1 1 2])`](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics)  to generate all the cases, and then filter based on the condition, but it is so inefficient when you have a large vector like `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]` and map like `{5 1, 6 2}(generate 1 set that contains 5 elements, and 2 sets that contain 6 elements)`. I just want to generate what I need at the first time, how can I do this job?

Comment: why `combinatorics` is inefficient ? "(combo/combinations [1 2 3] 2)" could help on this case. Make sure you partition the vector before using combinations

Answer (score 2):

In the specific example you give, there are 5,717,712 partitions that satisfy those constraints, and considerably more possibilities with no constraints.  So it's not so much that combinatorics is inefficient; I think you're simply underestimating how many possibilities there are.

The combinations function is a better tool for achieving the more direct combinations you are looking for.

In your example,

```
(def specific-partitions
  (let [initial-list [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]]   
    (for [c1 (combinations initial-list 5)
          :let [remainder1 (remove (set c1) initial-list)]
          c2 (combinations remainder1 6)
          :let [remainder2 (remove (set c2) remainder1)]]
      [c1 c2 remainder2])))

=>(take 10 specific-partitions)

([(1 2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9 10 11) (12 13 14 15 16 17)] 
 [(1 2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9 10 12) (11 13 14 15 16 17)] 
 [(1 2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9 10 13) (11 12 14 15 16 17)] 
 [(1 2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9 10 14) (11 12 13 15 16 17)] 
 [(1 2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9 10 15) (11 12 13 14 16 17)]
 [(1 2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9 10 16) (11 12 13 14 15 17)] 
 [(1 2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9 10 17) (11 12 13 14 15 16)]
 [(1 2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9 11 12) (10 13 14 15 16 17)]
 [(1 2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9 11 13) (10 12 14 15 16 17)]
 [(1 2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9 11 14) (10 12 13 15 16 17)])
```

It's still a rather large number of partitions, but at least you are now generating them directly.

From this example, you could generalize this technique to a function that takes an arbitrary map describing the partition structure, like you described in your question.

The specific code I've written here wouldn't work right if your initial set has duplicate elements; that would require a slightly different removal method.

Comment: actually it is possible to have duplicates elements, how to do then? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of duplicates?  In any case, calling 'distinct' on the result should work.